# Django: Why is my form sending POST data but returning request.method GET?

Tags: python, django

I expect the print(request.method) statement in my views.py to return POST below. I have seen other examples of code where request.method is POST. However my code simply outputs GET:

> test1
>
> GET

I can see that the form is sending POST data when I submit the info https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2vp8.jpg

After a bit of digging I found that HTTP is not designed to redirect POST data:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/99894/why-doesnt-http-have-post-redirect

But leads me to ask **why is my code redirecting this POST data**? I would expect my views to return "POST" not "GET" because I'm not using a HttpResponseRedirect for example. Would like to understand why this happening and what I can do to stop Django redirecting that POST data to get GET. What am I missing?

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name = 'index'),
    path('add_coin/', views.add_coin, name = 'add_coin'),
    path('register/', views.register, name = 'register'),
    path('login/', views.user_login, name='login'),
    path('logout/', views.user_logout, name='logout')
]
```

forms.py

```
class PortfolioForm(forms.ModelForm):
    coin = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = Coin.objects.all()) 
    amount = forms.IntegerField() 
    trade_price = forms.DecimalField(decimal_places = 2)

    field_order = ['coin', 'amount', 'trade_price']

    class Meta:
        model = Portfolio
        fields = {'coin', 'amount', 'trade_price', 'user'}
        exclude = ['user']
```

add_coin.html

```
<form action="{% url index %)" method="post" name="add_coin">
     <table>
          {{ form }}
     </table>
     {% csrf_token %}
     <input type="submit" name="add_coin" formmethod="post" value="Add Coin">
</form>
```

Index view (views.py)

```
def index(request):

    portfolio_list = []
    for coin in Portfolio.objects.filter(user = request.user): #(user = request.user.username):
        portfolio_dict = {}

        coin_str = str(coin.coin)

        portfolio_dict['coin'] = coin_str 
        portfolio_dict['amount'] = coin.amount 
        portfolio_dict['symbol'] = GetCoin(coin_str).symbol 
        portfolio_dict['price'] = GetCoin(coin_str).price 
        portfolio_dict['value'] = GetCoin(coin_str).price * coin.amount 
        portfolio_dict['last_updated'] = GetCoin(coin_str).last_updated 
        portfolio_dict['daily_change'] = GetCoin(coin_str).percent_change_24h
        portfolio_dict['gains'] = coin.trade_price - GetCoin(coin_str).price

        portfolio_list.append(portfolio_dict)
        #print(portfolio_list)  

    def get_top_coins(limit): # display coins if no user is logged in       
        data = requests.get("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/?limit={}".format(limit)).json()
        y = 0
        coin_list = {
            "image": [],
            "name": [],
            "price": [],
            "symbol": [],
            "market_cap": []
        }

        for x in data:
            coin_list["name"].append(data[y]['name'])
            coin_list["price"].append(data[y]['price_usd'])
            coin_list["symbol"].append(data[y]['symbol'])
            coin_list["market_cap"].append(data[y]['market_cap_usd'])

            y += 1 

        return coin_list

    coin_list = get_top_coins(20)

    for x in coin_list["name"]:
        image = "{}.png".format(x)
        coin_list["image"].append(image)

    context_dict = {'portfolio_list': portfolio_list, 'coin_list': zip(coin_list["image"], coin_list["name"], coin_list["price"], coin_list["market_cap"])}

    return render(request, 'myportfolio/index.html', context = context_dict)
```

add_coin view (Views.py):

```
def add_coin(request):
    print("test 1")
    print(request.method)
    form = PortfolioForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PortfolioForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print("test 2")
            obj = form.save(commit = False)
            obj.user = request.user
            obj.save()
        else: 
            print(form.errors)

    return render(request, 'myportfolio/add_coin.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: You should use `{% url 'index' %)` (with quotes) unless you want `index` to be treated as a variable. If you are posting to the index view, you should include that in your question.

Comment: I just changed that as you were commenting, it's now included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form appears to be handled by the `add_coin` view, so you should change the form action to post to it.

```
<form action="{% url 'add_coin' %}" method="post" name="add_coin">
```

Then I would expect to see

```
test1

GET
```

when you do the initial GET request to the `add_coin` view, and

```
test1

POST
```

when you submit the form with the POST request.

Comment: Thanks, this has uncovered a new issue with my URLS so I'm having to look into url namespaces now. When I hit submit on my form I get a Page not found error: `The current path, myportfolio/add_coin/{% url 'add_coin' %), didn't match any of these. `

Comment: That’s not a namespace issue. You copy-pasted the `%)` from my answer. It should be `%}`.